# Find specific word within string, return previous 4 characters from start of word

Tags: sql, db2

I need to add a calculated field to locate the word 'Month' within a string and then return the immediate numeric characters prior.

the field that this evaluation needs to be completed on is FIELD12.

There could be many string formats in this field. The important thing is that when the word month appears there will be at least 1 numeric digit immediately preceding it.

e.g.

- 6 Months Promo
- 12.99% for 120 Months
- Reduced for 12 Months

so on etc.

The code below is currently running fine. I have removed sensitive info.

```
SELECT  SAMPLETABLE.CRED_CARD_ID  
    , SAMPLETABLE.LN_ORIG_DT  
    , SAMPLETABLE.ACCT_STAT_DESC  
    , SAMPLETABLE.CURR_BAL_AMT  
    , SAMPLETABLE.TRM_MTH_NBR  
    , SAMPLETABLE.PROMO_END_DT  
    , SAMPLETABLE.PURCH_WNDW_END_DT  
    , SAMPLETABLE.PROMO_TRM_TXT  
    , SAMPLETABLE.FIELD12

FROM 
    DB.SAMPLETABLE SAMPLETABLE
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT  MAX(SAMPLETABLE_1.BI_DATA_AS_OF_DT) AS AS_OF_DT
    FROM DB.SAMPLETABLE SAMPLETABLE_1) Subquery
    ON (SAMPLETABLE.BI_DATA_AS_OF_DT = Subquery.AS_OF_DT) 
WHERE (SAMPLETABLE.ACCT_STAT_DESC = 'Open')
```

Comment: Something like `SUBSTR(FIELD12,LOCATE('Month', FIELD12)-4,4)`?

Comment: Using this I still receive that error:SQL0138N  A numeric argument of a built-in string function is out of range.  SQLSTATE=22011


SUBSTR(FIELD12,LOCATE('Month', FIELD12)-4,4)

Comment: @jarlh Note the characters that should be returning would be a number. In addition there would be a space on the end. Would that give the error?

Example string: Test Percentage for 120 Months until End

So i would want to return the 120. However sometimes it could be 60, or 6. Would there be a better way to only extract the previous numbers to the word month?

Comment: How about regular expression? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061492.html

Comment: Thanks henrik. I am relatively new to this. How would the statement look using the information above?

Some string examples: -4.99% for 6 Months until End (the number 6 would be returned) -Equal Payments for 120 months (the number 120 would be returned) -Equal Payments for 24 months (the number 24 would be returned)

Comment: @data_henrik forgot to tag.

Comment: Just needs a where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 regular expressions example.

```
select 
  t.FIELD12
, xmlcast(xmlquery('let $r := fn:replace($s, ".* (\d+) +month.*", "$1", "i") return if ($r castable as xs:integer) then xs:integer($r) else ()' passing ' '||t.FIELD12 as "s") as int) number
from table (values
  '4.99% for 6 Months until End'
, 'Equal Payments for 120 months'
, 'Equal Payments for 24 months'
, '1 month'
, 'wrong string'
, 'unknown number of months'
) t (FIELD12);
```

The result is:

```
FIELD12                         NUMBER
----------------------------    ------
4.99% for 6 Months until End         6
Equal Payments for 120 months      120
Equal Payments for 24 months        24
1 month                              1
wrong string                         -
unknown number of months             -
```

Should be something like this in your case:

```
SELECT  SAMPLETABLE.CRED_CARD_ID  
    , SAMPLETABLE.LN_ORIG_DT  
    , SAMPLETABLE.ACCT_STAT_DESC  
    , SAMPLETABLE.CURR_BAL_AMT  
    , SAMPLETABLE.TRM_MTH_NBR  
    , SAMPLETABLE.PROMO_END_DT  
    , SAMPLETABLE.PURCH_WNDW_END_DT  
    , SAMPLETABLE.PROMO_TRM_TXT  
    , SAMPLETABLE.FIELD12
    , xmlcast(xmlquery('let $r := fn:replace($s, ".* (\d+) +month.*", "$1", "i") return if ($r castable as xs:integer) then xs:integer($r) else ()' passing ' '||SAMPLETABLE.FIELD12 as "s") as int) as number
FROM 
    DB.SAMPLETABLE SAMPLETABLE
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT  MAX(SAMPLETABLE_1.BI_DATA_AS_OF_DT) AS AS_OF_DT
    FROM DB.SAMPLETABLE SAMPLETABLE_1) Subquery
    ON (SAMPLETABLE.BI_DATA_AS_OF_DT = Subquery.AS_OF_DT) 
WHERE (SAMPLETABLE.ACCT_STAT_DESC = 'Open');
```

[fn:replace](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/xqrfnrpl.html) function accepts your `SAMPLETABLE.FIELD12` as the 1-st parameter. The 2-nd parameter is a regular expression pattern the passed column value compared to. The meaning of the pattern `.* (\d+) +month.*` sub-elements:

`.*` - zero or more any characters

- one space

`(\d+)` - one or more digits; we surround them by `()` to reference it later

`+` - one or more spaces

`month` - string constant

`.*` - zero or more any characters

If the column value complies this pattern, the whole value is replaced by the 1-st (and the only) group value (surrounded by `()` in the pattern, we reference this by `$1` in the 3-rd parameter of the function).
If not, then the column value is untouched.
Finally, we try to cast the replaced value to `int` using xpath expression. It returns `NULL` if such a cast is unsuccessful.

Comment: Thank you. The results you show are exactly what is needed. However I am coding in Toad Data Point and it is not recognizing the xmlcast. Thoughts?

Comment: What does it mean: `not recognizing the xmlcast`? Aren’t you able to run this statement with this tool? What’s the error?

Comment: Perhaps I am not adding the code in correctly. I am attempting to use a calculated field to produce this number. Your code in addition to mine shown below with sensitive data removed.

SELECT  FIELD1.ID  
 , FIELD2. 
 , FIELD3.ACCT_STAT 
 , FIELD4 CURR 
 , FIELD5.TRM 
 , FIELD12.PLAN_DESC   
 , REGEXP_SUBSTR(T_MTH_PORTF.PLAN_DESC ,'(\d{1,4})\s+month',1,1,'i',1)AS test3
FROM schema.table

Comment: using the xml case i get this error: SQL0104N  An unexpected token "AS" was found following ""s") as int) number".  Expected tokens may include:  "INTO".  SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: Your query contains too many errors. Please, change your initial post to provide DDL of your `schema.table` table, sample data, and result needed.

Comment: Apologies. Let me go back and tidy up my query. It is working as is until I add the statement(s) above. Pardon my ignorance, can you elaborate on DDL? I've revised my initial post to include a working version of my code with sensitive data removed. The number your code is returning is exaclty what I need. Please let me know if you need me to do anything else.

Comment: `DDL` means [Data definition language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language). Check my amended answer.

Comment: Oh man. You are my hero. Thank you for your patience!

Would you be able to explain what is going on in the syntax?

xmlcast(xmlquery('let $r := fn:replace($s, ".* (\d+) +month.*", "$1", "i") return if ($r castable as xs:integer) then xs:integer($r) else ()' passing ' '||SAMPLETABLE.FIELD12 as "s") as int) as number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187523/discussion-between-user1590497-and-mark-barinstein).

Comment: One more question. I just noticed a few out of my 1M values has the number with no space between the month e.g. 9months. Is there a way to account for this?

Comment: Sure. Use the following pattern: `.* (\d+) *month.*` instead.

Comment: It all is beginning to make sense. Thank you for you help. Have a great week!

Answer (score 1):

I often solve this problem just by appending a `'Month'` to the end of the string.  More likely, though, you want a `case` expression:

```
select (case when Field12 like '%Month%' then SUBSTR(FIELD12, LOCATE('Month', FIELD12), -4) end)
```

Comment: I will be adding a case statement once I can get it to return what it is suppose to without an error.

Comment: Lastly, we are using db2 version 10.05

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Db2 supports the `REGEXP` functions (e..g if on Db2 11.1 for LUW), you would find `REGEXP_SUBSTR` https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061497.html more flexable. E.g.

```
SELECT 
  T.FIELD12
, REGEXP_SUBSTR(FIELD12,'(\d{1,4})\s+month',1,1,'i',1) AS REGEX_SOLUTION
, SUBSTR(FIELD12,NULLIF(LOCATE('months',lower(FIELD12)),0)-4,4) AS SUBSTR_SOLUTION
FROM TABLE (VALUES
  '4.99% for 6 Months until End'
, 'Equal Payments for 120 months adn 12 months'
, 'Equal Payments for 24 months'
, '1 month'
, 'wrong string'
, 'unknown number of months'
) T (FIELD12);
```

gives

```
 FIELD12                                        REGEX_SOLUTION  SUBSTR_SOLUTION
 -------------------------------------------    --------------  ---------------
 4.99% for 6 Months until End                   6               r 6 
 Equal Payments for 120 months adn 12 months    120             120 
 Equal Payments for 24 months                   24               24 
 1 month                                        1               NuLL
 wrong string                                   NuLL            NuLL
 unknown number of months                       NuLL             of
```

Comment: Toad Data Point also looks to be having issues with this too.
Error Message:  SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "REGEXP_SUBSTR" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884

Answer (score 0):

***Suppress the case where the index is negative to fix out of bounds error***

```
select 
SUBSTR(FIELD12,LOCATE('Month', FIELD12),-4)
from mytable

where LOCATE('Month', FIELD12) > 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Mark-Barinstein !!! The below statement works perfectly.

xmlcast(xmlquery('let $r := fn:replace($s, ".* (\d+) +month.*", "$1", "i") return if ($r castable as xs:integer) then xs:integer($r) else ()' passing ' '||SAMPLETABLE.FIELD12 as "s") as int) as number